# Splitting string with the index of Out of Range

Tags: java, runtime-error

I tried to code the logic to print whether the given string is permutation of other string,
  An Run time error occurred

> "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

I have accessed only two index of String Array.

->The given String is separated by two spaces.

```
public static String permute(String str){
    String[] st=str.split("\\s+");
    String sr1=st[0].toString();//Run time error
    String sr2=st[1].toString();
}
```

> Run Time Error  Msg: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Kindly help from this error.

Comment: Show us the `String` you are trying to split. Thanks

Comment: The pattern used to `split()` doesn't literally say `two spaces`, but *one or more spaces* - what if there is no space, what if second string was *all spaces*?.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're assuming that you'll get two items in the array, which is not the case for all inputs.
You should consider the array size:

```
public static String permute(String str){
    String[] st=str.split("\\s+");
    for (String item : st) {
       // do whatever
    }
}
```

If you want to handle only the first two items regardless if there are more, do something like `for (int i = 0 ; i < st.length && i < 2 ; i++)`, but always validate the length of the array before you access its items